# User /settings route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Simple question:

I have added the following to my routes. rb

```
match 'settings' => 'users#edit'
```

I'm trying to make a user settings page at /settings (just with the edit form and the update button).

I have created the edit/update methods in my User controller, and added the edit view and _form.

For some reason when I go to /settings I am getting:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

(Even though users#show exists)

Strangely, I can get it to work fine to route to users#show if I change my routes.rb - but that's not what I want!

I guess I'm missing something obvious - can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show us the link_to code?

Comment: Agree with @MurifoX, the error is most likely in your views (edit or form)

Comment: Correct :) turns out commenting out my link_to fixed it.. My code is `= link_to 'Cancel', user_path` - how can I modify this to point to the right place?

Comment: Turns out user_path(@user) works, am I right in saying I need to pass the @user as it is not implicit by the resource path? i.e. we don't have a /users/:id in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out commenting out my link_to fixed it..

Answer (score 1):

Does this issue go away when you restart your dev server? Routes are funny when created after the server is running.